# How do you call a map which sends convergent sequences to pre-compact ones ?

Tags: gn.general-topology, terminology

In my work I encountered a map $f$ between two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ that was not continuous (at least I couldn't prove it was), but I was able to prove that convergent sequences $(x_n)$ in $X$ were sent by $f$ to sequences lying in a compact set in $Y$ (in particular, any subsequence of $f(x_n)$ had a convergent subsequence).

Do these kind of maps have a name ?

Thanks.

Comment: If nobody comes up with an extant name, I suggest "Bolzano maps".

Comment: You could be the Godfather, so you could name them anyway you please.

Comment: Your condition on $f$ is equivalent to: $f(A)$ is pre-compact for any pre-compact $A$. So in the trend of "open map" and "closed map", I would call it a "pre-compact map".